# Async Function Not Getting Called

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.5

Please forgive me for any noobish mistakes seen below, I'm learning some of the concepts I'm attempting to work with.

**Problem:**
While debugging my app, I was able to call an `async` function with `Task.Start()`. I felt that the app was in a working state for the phase I'm in so removed all breakpoints with CTRL + SHIFT + F9.

Once I ran the app with no breakpoints it would fail due to a property not getting populated. Now when I try to debug any breakpoint I set in the `async` function that handles most of the work is longer hit. It's like it is getting skipped. Can anyone see a reason why `GetWowAuctionFileInfo` isn't being called?

`GetWowAuctionFileInfo` is what is not getting called, or at least appears to be not getting called.

Thanks.

**Relevant Code**

*Caller Function*

```
    private void buttonTestJSFCHI_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        JSON_Worker w = new JSON_Worker();
        w.StartTask("FileInfo", "https://us.api.battle.net/wow/auction/data/medivh?locale=en_US&apikey=<guid>");
        foreach (string res in w.ReturnedData)
        {
            textBoxResults.Text += res;
        }
    }
```

*Called Functions*

```
public void StartTask(string TaskName, string optionalUri= "no_uri_passed")
    {
        if (TaskName == "FileInfo")
        {
            //Need to use a lamba expression to call a delegate with a parameter
            if (!(optionalUri == "no_uri_passed"))
            {
                Task t = new Task(() => GetWowAuctionFileInfo(optionalUri));
                t.Start();
                //Func<string> function = new Func<string>(() => GetWowAuctionFileInfo(optionalUri));
                //Task<string> tInfo = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetWowAuctionFileInfo(optionalUri));
            }
        }
    }
private async void GetWowAuctionFileInfo(string auctionInfoUri)
    {
        RealmJSFileCheck realmInfoObject;
        List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 3; attempt++)
                {
                    var response = await client.GetAsync(auctionInfoUri);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        realmInfoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RealmJSFileCheck>(content);
                        returnValue = ConvertFileInfoToConsumableList(realmInfoObject);
                        //returnValue = realmInfoObject.files.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException iOpEx)
        {
           //recieved this when an invalid uri was passed in 
        }

        ReturnedData = returnValue;
    }

    private List<string> ConvertFileInfoToConsumableList(RealmJSFileCheck jsfc)
    {
        List<string> returnData = new List<string>();
        if (jsfc.files.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("File URL: ");
            sb.Append(jsfc.files[0].url);
            returnData.Add(sb.ToString());

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Last Modified: ");
            sb.Append(jsfc.files[0].lastModified);
            returnData.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            returnData.Add("No File Info Found");
        }
        return returnData;
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks again all for the detailed commentary. I've gone through much documentation regarding Task usage and learned a lot in this exercise. I'm marking the answer from @Johnathon as the solution because it provided exactly what I was asking for and provided a very helpful link for more information.

Comment: without addressing your underline issue... you should just do `Task.Run(() => GetWowAuctionFileInfo(optionalUri))` instead of constructing a task and then explicitly starting it.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, as best practices, asyn methods should NOT return void but return Task. The only exception is when it is for events.

Comment: @CodingYoshi agreed, except at least two of the three current answers state that..

Comment: Thanks all for the comments and answers. I knew going into this that I had a ton to learn so just dove right in. I'm currently digesting all of the info and reading over the guide suggested by @Johnathon. Once I've determined which way to go. I will mark an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GetWowAuctionFileInfo` method is an asynchronous method, and you await an async call within it without returning a Task. In general it is bad practice to use `async void`. Instead, turn your `GetWowAuctionFileInfo` method into `async Task<List<string>> GetWowAuctionFileInfo`. This will let you await the `GetAsync` call, parse the data, and return the collection to the caller without having to use a `ReturnObject`.

```
private async Task<List<string>> GetWowAuctionFileInfo(string auctionInfoUri)
{
    RealmJSFileCheck realmInfoObject;
    List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            for (int attempt = 0; attempt < 3; attempt++)
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(auctionInfoUri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    realmInfoObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RealmJSFileCheck>(content);

                    // You can just return the List<T> now.
                    return ConvertFileInfoToConsumableList(realmInfoObject);
                    //returnValue = realmInfoObject.files.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException iOpEx)
    {
       //recieved this when an invalid uri was passed in 
    }
}
```

Because the method was originally `async void`, you could not await the calling of it in your `buttonTestJSFCHI_Click`. Now that we've made it all Task based, you can await it within your event handler. Note that event handlers are generally the only acceptable place to use `async void`. Any time you are responsible for the creation of the methods, and not constrained by a contract (like event handlers), you should always return a Task on your async methods.

```
private async void buttonTestJSFCHI_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    JSON_Worker w = new JSON_Worker();
    List<string> results = await w.StartTask("FileInfo", "https://us.api.battle.net/wow/auction/data/medivh?locale=en_US&apikey=<guid>");
    foreach (string res in results)
    {
        textBoxResults.Text += res;
    }
}

public async Task<List<string>> StartTask(string TaskName, string optionalUri= "no_uri_passed")
{
    if (TaskName == "FileInfo")
    {
        //Need to use a lamba expression to call a delegate with a parameter
        if (!(optionalUri == "no_uri_passed"))
        {
            // Since the GetWowAuctionFileInfo now returns Task, we don't need to create a new one. Just await the Task given back to us, and return the given result.
            return await GetWowAuctionFileInfo(optionalUri);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason you saw the expected result while debugging is because the debug session was slow enough that the async operation completed in time for your code to use it. When running the app outside of the debugger, it runs faster than the async operation could complete, preventing you from seeing the data. Thus the need to `await` the entire async call stack, so you can prevent further execution from happening down that code-path until you receive all of the desired data.

[Microsoft has a good write up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) on Task based programming, I'd take a read through it to help you understand it some.

*EDIT*

Just to clarify, when you return a `Task<T>` on your methods, you will be given the result when you await. For example:

```
List<string> result = await StartTask();
```

Even though `StartTask` returns `Task<List<string>>`, the `await` operation will wait for the `StartTask()` method to complete, and then unwrap the result from the `Task<T>` object and give you the result back automatically. So don't let the method signature fool you, if you `await` it, you will be given back the resulting data, and not the actual `Task` itself. There won't be any need for you to pull the data out of the `Task` manually.

Comment: I think it useless using `await` in `StartTask`. this method do only validation and calling asynchronous method after that. Useless because when you calling `await` the method will be rewritten by compiler and added some "synchronization" magic which is useless in case if validation fails.

Comment: Yes, but teaching the OP when to use await and when not to use await is outside of the scope of this post. The OP doesn't understand the basic concepts of async/await. I wasn't about to try and explain when you should and shouldn't await your Tasks. That's why I linked him to the TPL documentation instead. I agree that in general there is overhead (albeit very marginal, the compiler makes it extremely efficient), but in this case he'll be fine.

Comment: Same as changing signature of the method to return a list - isn't relevant at all. :)

Comment: yes I have downvoted your answer only for reason of misleading explanation. If you agree with me - I will be glad to add +1 for your correction

Comment: I already said I agreed. For the record, my Answer is in no way misleading. It's working code, that anyone can read and know exactly what is happening. Awaiting a Task rather than returning it is far from misleading and gives the expected results.

Comment: But you didn't update your answer :) Sorry again, but changing signature of method to return value has "really" nothing to do with his problem.

Comment: To each there own. I don't need a +1. I could care less - I just find your downvoting my answer *after* our disagreement in your Answer distasteful. Really comes across as payback. I'm not here for the votes, so downvote away.

Answer (score 1):

Because you not waiting for result.
You loop with `ReturnedData` before it was assigned with data.

I think you don't need to create new `Task` at all. Make `GetWowAuctionFileInfo` method properly asynchronous which returns `Task`.

```
private async Task GetWowAuctionFileInfo(string auctionInfoUri)
{
    // same code
}
```

Change `StartTask` to return `Task`. Because we not awaiting result here we don't need make method asynchronous.
Suggest to change name of this method to `LoadData` for example, which give more information about what this method does.

```
public Task StartTask(string TaskName, string optionalUri= "no_uri_passed")
{
    if (TaskName == "FileInfo")
    {
        //Need to use a lamba expression to call a delegate with a parameter
        if (!(optionalUri == "no_uri_passed"))
        {
            return GetWowAuctionFileInfo(optionalUri) // this will return Task
        }
    }

    // if validation fails - return completed task or throw exception
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Then you can call it in `Button_Click` event handler

```
private async void buttonTestJSFCHI_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    JSON_Worker w = new JSON_Worker();
    await w.StartTask("FileInfo", "yourUrl");

    // This line will be executed only after asynchronous methods completes succesfully 
    // or exception will be thrown
    foreach (string res in w.ReturnedData)
    {
        textBoxResults.Text += res;
    }
}
```

Comment: His `GetWowAuctionFileInfo` will not contain the same code. He needs to remove the assignment to `ReturnData` and instead return the `List<string>` he creates. It's a minor tweak, but it needs to be done. Just changing it to `async Task` won't solve it.

Comment: this seemed like it was leading to a good answer.. but making `GetWowAuctionFileInfo` public was a bit of an odd and irrelevant instruction.

Comment: Agreed, it can stay private. He also has to change the method signatures, otherwise all he'll be given back a Task with no accessible result. The signatures need to be `async Task<List<string>> GetWowAuctionFileInfo` and the same change applied to `StartTask`

Comment: suggestion for `public` removed. But changing method to return result is not relevant. OP's logic was to retrieve data and save it to the property. Changing logic to return data will not affect on the main question. But I am agree that `StartTask` is some misleading name for the method. So I suggested to change it

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger it's a void method originally.. we wasn't returning data .. he is assigning it to some out of scope variable. so long as the task to do that is returned.. however, this would likely return `Task<Task>` from `StartTask` that is

Comment: Yeah, I guess I understand that reasoning. I would have just had him return the value all the way up the stack, instead of the top calling event handler having knowledge that the underlying code he's calling will manipulate some top-level member. Probably outside the scope of the OP's question though.

Comment: I was incorrect about `Task<Task>` here.. I thought I might have been after saying it actually... though, you will need to add `return Task.Run(() => {});` to the end of `StartTask`.. to supply some task back to caller and satisfy the `all code paths return` compiler error

Comment: You don't need waste a thread with `Task.Run...` for this. You can return completed task there to satisfy compiler `return Task.CompletedTask;`. I have updated answer